# Mail ticket system for suport / helpdesk with IMAP SSL suport (certificates)

Tags: helpdesk

I have been looking for some helpdesk (OpenSource or free) that I can use with the support of IMAP mail with SSL and certificates. If is coded in PHP all will be easier (for me).

I've tried "eTicket Support" and "osTicket" and they are not supporting this.

The second, the osTicket, supports IMAP but is having troubles with SSL and certificates.

Can someone orientate me?

Thank you in advance!

PS: Sorry I can't post links because I'm new here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a huge fan of [Request Tracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/).  While it may not meet your exact technology requirements, I would suggest considering it anyway.

Comment: I was looking it... I've a dedicated server. What software I need to run it? Sorry my English is not my main language and it's hard for me. Thank u in advance!

Comment: It runs using Perl on Apache.  http://wiki.bestpractical.com/view/InstallationGuides

Comment: I agree with Warner, RT is a great product. To run it you'll need apache, mod_perl (or fastcgi), perl, and a bunch of perl modules. Fortunately, RT ships with a script that will install all of the perl modules for you if you choose. For fetching mail, it uses fetchmail, which does have support for IMAPS.

Comment: @Isern Palaus, take a look at this : http://github.com/bestpractical/rt/raw/stable/README